# Ansible Proxy error while trying to install Edx

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, pip, ansible, edx

I was trying to install EdX following these instructions https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-64-bit-Installation

But I always get stuck on the Task [common | Add python-pycurl]

And then I received a timeout caused by pip, caused due to pip is not receiving my proxy settings.

So how can I globally pass the https_proxy environment variable to every task on ansible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For pip if you want to avoid editing every single task you have the option of droping a pip config file http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file and set a proxy in the `[global]` section.

It will need to be in the home directory of the user that you are running ansible as.